# jsonencoderdecoder without getter/setter method

Tags: json, gwt, resty-gwt

I used the RestyGWT's JsonEncoderDecoder interface to encode/decode some objects. Among them there are instances of classes having properties not exposed using getter/setter methods. I tried annotating corresponding properties with `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty`. But it's not working, causing error

> [ERROR] [jsonsample] - field must not be private: com.mycompany.jsonsample.ItemList.items

`com.mycompany.jsonsample.ItemList` is the class with property `items` which has no getter/setter and annotated as said above.

Also is it possible to tell the encoder/decoder to skip some properties?

Comment: Can you give the json you want to deserialize with resty and the classes involved ?

Answer (score 0):

Example with private field and annotated constructor, you should provide more info on your problem though.

```
public abstract class Parent
{    
    @JsonCreator
    public Parent(@JsonProperty("name") String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    private String name;
}
```